# How to add errors after FormRequests validation?

Tags: laravel

How to add errors after FormRequests validation?

password_repository->update() will return an error if the current passwords entered do not match.

password_repository->update() calls an external API.

I want to add an error in the controller depending on the return value of the repository.

In PasswordRequest, validation after calling the external API cannot be described, so I am in trouble.

For this reason I want to add an error in the controller after doing password_repository->update().

PasswordController.php

```
public function completeEdit(PasswordRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->only(['password', 'new_password']);

    $data = $this->password_repository->update($input);

    //I want to add an error at this point!!!

    return view('pages.password.edit.complete');
    }

}
```

PasswordRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PasswordRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'password' => 'required',
            'new_password' => 'required|confirmed',
            'new_password_confirmation' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Read documents first. "Adding After Hooks To Form Requests" [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#creating-form-requests)

Comment: Thanks.
I know the after hook can be used in withValidator.

But is $data in the controller available in withValidator?

Thank you.

Comment: yes, using `$this->input('abc')`. Use that code in withValidator function to get input value.

Comment: The $data I mean is the variable defined in PasswordController.php above, not the value contained in the request parameter!

Comment: You should move external service code into separate (i.e. `Repository\\PasswordRepository`) class and then include/call that class from Request class but also you should use after hook as proposed above. That way you would have sorted code as should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect with errors could help you.

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
     'Password not correct',
]);
```

Or return to a specific route.

```
return redirect()->route('password.create')->withErrors([
     'Password not correct',
]);
```

Comment: Usually work in context of apis, did a more blade oriented approach now

Comment: It went well! Thanks!

Comment: super :) if it helped remember to accept it as an answer